# Default Image Isn't Displaying When Setting Image

Tags: swift, database, image, default, placeholder

I am trying to set the default avatar image to a "ninja" image. Default image isn't showing however with this code. Not sure what is wrong.

```
        ProfileService.showOtherUser(user: bet.sentToUser) { [weak self] (profile2) in
              self?.profile2 = profile2
              if (profile2?.imageURL == "") {
                  cell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "ninja")
              }else{
                  let imageURL = URL(string: ((profile2?.imageURL ?? "")))
                  cell.userImage.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Check if the filename matches properly (case-sensitive). Also, do it on the main thread.

Comment: filename matches

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in storyboard to your image view this way till you not change it programmatically it will remain the default one